# Changing app name changes the link of the app?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I have an app on the app store and I want to change its name with an update , if I change the name of app , will the link of app be changed ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if you'll change only the name and keep bundle Id in old form. When you'll change bundle Id then you'll need to create new app in appstore.

---

EDIT

By default all names are derrived from PRODUCT_NAME:

[image]

you'll need to remove variables from there and enter names manually (and keep bundle ID not changed).

Comment: I confused with the link on the app store is containing the app name , did you experience it before ?

Comment: that does not matter, see this: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/asdasdasd/id578147041?ls=1&mt=8 , still works ;) what matter in this link is numerical ID

Comment: anyway, the 'official' link will change, but old links will work as well

Answer (score 3):

As long as the app Id does not change. The answer is no, your app link refers to your app by its numerical Id not the name. Hope that helps. Adrian

Edit

The name of the app can be changed in info.plist of your app and id number you see after the name of the does not change. Just go to the info.plist of your app and change the bundle name.

Comment: The link on the app store containing the name of app like this , my app name is Stupid Balls for now and the link : https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stupid-balls/id578147041?ls=1&mt=8

Comment: This is the right way, don't rename the target.

Comment: By default bundle name is the target name you can hardcore it instead of using project defined variables.

Comment: I did it and I know that , my question is the link on the app store will change or not ? I'm asking because I have sent an update for existing app and changed its name . And I have sent an lite version app and using the app link in that lite version binary , Thanks .

Comment: No it will be fine as I mentioned. The link will be the same just the name will change.

Comment: And these 2 ones are waiting for review now

Comment: If you like you can check my answer as the correct one which I'll appreciate.